# Persistent data with Cordova on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, local-storage, localforage

I'm developing a leaderboard for my game (written in JS) and I need to locally store some user's infos between more .html and .js pages, just like the username for the login and bestscore.

I did it using localStorage and on the desktop browser it worked with no issue at all, same for the Android app wrapped with Cordova. However, testing it in iOS resulted in localStorage wiped out on every app restart! Googling it out I decided to switch to localForage. Again, Android and Desktop (Chrome on Mac) works just fine but on iOS datas get wiped out when app is closed from the multitasking. I tried both WEBSQL and INDEXEDDB as localForage drivers. I tested on two different iPhones (iOS 10.3.2 and iOS 10.3.3) and both were NOT running out of memory. I use CocoonJS to wrap the files. Any help please? Don't absolutely know where this issue is coming from. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What about cookies?

Comment: You can use a simple sqlite database. https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage

Answer (score 1):

About LocalStorage on ios

> iOS stores localStorage data in a location that may be cleaned out by the OS when space is required.

You can try plugin-based, [sql-lite](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage#readme) or something like it.

Comment: I'm 99% sure space was not required on iPhone I used, they were not out of memory....As for sql-lite, same solution proposed by @Phil.. But from what i read [here](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage#status), i doubt CocoonJS is supported... Do you know more about?

Comment: `CocoonJS` is competitor of `PhoneGap` and must have better perfomance, because PhoneGap using native web view, CocoonJS integrating its wev view

Comment: They are cordova-based, but have own set of plugins.

Comment: After I used once PhoneGap  + [framework7](https://framework7.io/docs/template7.html) I'm using cordova + vuejs.

Comment: So definitely I will try it and hope for the best. But the doubt will remain: why localStorage/Forage were not working on iOS? God knows..

Comment: It like ios stores it in temporary data and clean when space is required (and in most cases it's required to optimize system). Oh it's one more technology Service Worker to cache some data.